# Comput this limit withou L'Hospital's rule

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

How can I find $\lim \limits_{x\to 0} \frac{x \sin^2 x}{(\arctan 5x)^2}$ without using l'Hopital's rule?

I understand that I can simplify the numerator but what should I do with the denominator?

Comment: the expression inside the limit is not clear. Is it $\sin^2 X$?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**. Write 
$$ \frac{x \sin^2 x}{\arctan^2 5x} 
 = \left(\frac{\arctan 5x}{5x}\right)^{-2} \cdot \left(\frac{\sin x}x\right)^2 
   \cdot \frac{x \cdot x^2}{25 x^2} $$
Now use the (hopefully known) limits of $\frac{\arctan x}{x}$ and $\frac{\sin x}x$ for $x \to 0$.